# What legacy OS/Web server could have used CGI EXE files of type "ELF 32-bit MSB executable MIPS SYSV"?

Tags: unix, web, mips, cgi, legacy

This is a complete shot in the dark, but I have some hope.

I am attempting to resurrect a (large) legacy web application from around 1999-2001 in a VM. The application has a `cgi-local` folder with a bunch of `.exe` files, so I (wrongly) assumed that the app ran on Windows 2000 Server back in its day.

This was the wrong assumption, because none of the files run in my Windows 2003 VM.

Running `file` against them on a Linux machine yields this:

`ordel.exe: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-II version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /usr/lib/libc.so.1, stripped`

I was hoping someone might give me an idea, a clue, or any kind of pointer as to what system this could have possibly run on? Any ideas or suggestions are welcome...

This was before my time so I am not sure where to even start.

I am guessing this was some kind of UNIX, but have never heard of MIPS-based web servers (or UNIX platforms that used the `.exe` extension).

**Edit:** This may have been a SPARC system. I've learned that the actual CGI files belong to a product called Mercantec SoftCart, which may have targetted "BSDi".

Comment: In what form do you have the web application? A software package? An archived bunch of files? Can you add a list of files to your question? There might be a hint to the OS somewhere. Running `strings ordel.exe` might also show interesting information. (There may be lots of output.)

Comment: If it is a commercial product, the software might be locked to a specific machine or a time range as copy protection.

Answer (score 0):

On a UNIX or Linux system, the concept of "file extensions" does not exist at the OS level. The `.exe` is simply the end of the file name. The OS can execute binary programs or scripts with any file name. Usually the file names would not have any "extension". You could rename `ordel.exe` to `ordel` or even `ordel.txt` and it would execute fine, as long as the execute permission is set.

Only applications or file managers might require the file name to end with a specific pattern. In your case, for example, the web server might (be configured to) require binary CGI program files to have name ending with `.exe`.

The binaries might depend on a specific OS.

I remember a few MIPS based operating systems:

- RISC/os https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_RISC/os
- SINIX or Reliant UNIX https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SINIX
- ULTRIX https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrix, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DECstation
- OSF/1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSF/1

(There might be more.)